# Should I use ~ or \mbox?

Tags: symbols, boxes, punctuation, characters

`~` stands for a non-breaking space, and `\mbox{<text>}` creates a box with text in it that cannot be broken (since its a "box").
I understand that `\mbox` has broader application than `~` (e.g. when you put not text only, but also pictures in it).

However, considering text only, **what is the difference between `~` and `\mbox`?** And when should I use the one or the other in following circumstances?

- A phone number: 012345678901
- A page number abbreviation : p.210sq.
- A two-parts family name : Jean de LaFontaine
- Punctuation: *(in french)* «Oh là là: c'est un cul-de-sac!»

Comment: `\mbox` produces non-streatchable spaces, while `~` produces a space which stretches as the other spaces on the same line

Comment: A good use for `\mbox` with text is to disallow breaking of things that contain hyphens.  For example, I write a lot of documents that contain our company's part numbers.  An example is `\mbox{040-24800}`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In none of the presented cases you should use `\mbox`.

- Phone numbers should use a kern, such as `123\,456\,7890`
- Things such as `p.~210~sq.\@` should use a tie (note the `\@` in order not to make the period as a sentence ending one)
- Names should use `~`: `Jean de~La~Fontaine` (you may want to remove the first `~` if line breaking becomes otherwise unfeasible)
- Space before French punctuations (but after `«`) should be a kern; the only exception is the colon, where `~:<space>` should be used.

For French punctuation, leave the job to `babel-french` that usually works well.

What's the difference between `p.~210` and `\mbox{p. 210}`? In the former case, the space is not considered to be after a sentence ending period and it still participates to stretching and shrinking together with all other spaces in the line. In the latter case, the space is fixed and `.` is sentence ending; so it will probably be much bigger than other spaces in the line. You might cure this by doing `\mbox{p.\@ 210}` or `\mbox{.\ 210}`, but still this space will usually be different from other spaces in the same line, because it's rigid.

Answer (score 23):

The `\mbox` is totally unbreakable, i.e., it does not allow hyphenation nor any other breaks.

The tilde `~` inserts an unbreakable space, but does not affect the breakability of its left and right neighbours. So in `La~Fontaine` the Fountaine part can still be hyphenated.

So, the tilde is easier to type and to read in the TeX source and it has the other advantage that its neighbours can be hyphenated.